# How to make Oracle database services not start when I turn on my laptop

Tags: services, oracle, database

How do I get Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 services to not start at boot until I manually activate them? As it is, I have to run `sudo service oracle-xe stop` to stop the services every boot.

Comment: Which Oracle services do you refer to? How did you install them?

Comment: The "Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2" services.

Comment: I gotta do 'sudo service oracle-xe stop' every time I turn on my laptop